# Returning Top 10 Most Used Words in Speech Excluding a List of Words with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need some help figuring out how to do this. I know you do it with Hashes so here's what I've got so far.

```
count = Hash.new()
speech {|word| count[word] += 1}
```

and I'm kind of stuck after that. How would I go about returning the top 10 words? Would it be something like this?

```
count.sort
return count[1..10]
```

Also, how would I got about excluding any words from the list that I don't want included? Would it be something like this?

```
wanted_words = speech.select { |word| !excluded_words.include?(word) }
```

Elaboration for Arup:

So say I have this hash:

```
hash = Hash.new()
hash["cats"] = 1
hash["blaks"] = 2
hash["Pogs"] = 13
hash["Dogs"] = 12
```

How would I create a list of the top 2 words with the greatest values?
Basically, I want "Pogs" and "Dogs" returned because those have the greatest values (13 and 12 respectively).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

**max_by(n) → obj**

> If the `n` argument is given, minimum `n` elements are returned as an array.

```
count.max(10) { |_, v| v }
```

As per the second question use [`#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) :

```
speech.reject { |word| excluded_words.include?(word) }
```

There is a *bang* version although [`#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject-21). Use which one fits with your need.

**update**

```
hash = Hash.new()
hash["cats"] = 1
hash["blaks"] = 2
hash["Pogs"] = 13
hash["Dogs"] = 12

hash.max_by(2) { |_, v| v } # => [["Pogs", 13], ["Dogs", 12]]
hash.max_by(2) { |_, v| v }.map(&:first) # => ["Pogs", "Dogs"]
```

Note : `#min`, `#min_by`, `#max` and `#max_by` supports [optional argument](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L41) to return multiple elements from **Ruby 2.2.0** onwards.

Comment: I tried hash.max(10) but it doesn't return the highest to lowest.

Comment: I elaborated on it in my post.

Comment: Don't forget that (as you pointed out in a previous answer), `max_by`, `min_by` and `minimax_by` did not take an argument prior to Ruby 2.2.

Comment: ...or `hash.keys.max_by(2) { |k| hash[k] }`.

Comment: I would use `_` instead  of `k` since it is unused.

Comment: @MarkThomas I agree. I missed it there somehow.. :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Done. I sometimes forget what current Ruby version is set by default in my _bash_ shell. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
hash.max_by(2) { |k, v| [v, k] }.map(&:first)
```

Comment: Btw I didn't see your solution while posting. Well, `[v, k]` is to preserve "Pogs" > "Dogs", but I see your solution works either well.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are multiple ways of doing things in ruby.

```
hash
  .sort_by { |_, value| value }
  .collect { |key, _| key }
  .last(2)
```

Not necessarily better than what is already suggested, but I like the way how it translates to an english sentence, making it easy to follow along.

Comment: I suggest you reverse `collect` and `take`: `hash.sort_by { |_, value| value }.last(2).collect(&:first)`.